# My php if condition is running no matter what. Trying to get user id Joomla 3

Tags: javascript, php, joomla3.0

So in Joomla 3 I am trying to get the user's logged in status and run some code accordingly.
I am using JFactory's method getUser() and then checking if that user is a guest or logged in. When I use the code below the if statement will run no matter what. Can someone explain to me what is happening and maybe a better way  of acheiving what I want?

```
<?php
$user=JFactory::getUser();
$status=$user->guest;
if($status == 1){
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        popup();
    </script>';
}
?>
```

I've tried it multiple different ways, even just using if(JFactory::getUser()->guest)... didn't work.

Comment: _"both the if and else will run no matter what"_, you dont have an else statement here

Comment: I did i just forgot to add it here. My thing is that not even the if statement should run when a user is logged in, but it does.

Comment: have you tried `var_dump($status)` to make sure it is 0 when logged in?

Comment: nope, no idea what that even is. ^^ I am very new to php, I don't take a php course till my next semester. Only reason I'm screwing with it now is a site I'm working for a school on needs it.

Comment: [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is a function to dump information about a variable. Put it after you set `$status` and it will print out information when you load the page.

Comment: Once check the status.. Check whether it is 0 or 1 when you log in..